# Converting a string to mulitple floats

Tags: python, string

I would like to convert a "list"  string into a list with two float items.  Unfortunately the list is imported as one long string.
Original:

```
a = '[123.34 , -12333]'
```

This is one big long string in which converting to float with map(float, a) returns: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: [`

New:

```
a = [123.34, -12333]
```

Where 123.34 and -12333 are each individual float numbers

I've tried `eval(a)`.  This worked somewhat, but would make all the negative numbers into positive.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Not very clear what you need. Please try to rephrase.

Comment: * make all the negative numbers into positive* : I cant reproduce that, eval(a) must work.

Answer (score 3):

You need convert the string to list first

```
a = '[123.34 , -12333]'
res = map(float, a[1:-1].split(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the existing answer, since you've a python list in the form of string you can also use, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
f1, f2 = ast.literal_eval(a)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> f1, f2 = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> f1
123.34
>>> f2
-12333
```

`literal_eval` is used to safely evaluate an **expression** or a **`Unicode`** or **Latin-1** encoded string containing a `Python` literal.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions

```
a = '[123.34 , -12333]'
string_list = a[1:-1].split(',')
res = [float(entry) for entry in string_list]
```